# how to use parameters in add_url_rule flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a script to basically create all the flask endpoint from existing python classes/methods.

one way which i came across was app.add_url_rule

but it is not working for me

```py
@app.route('/username/<username>')
def userstatus(username):
    print("user is logged in")
app.add_url_rule('/username/', 'userstatus', defaults={"username":None})**
```

the above one is working but if i remove `@app.route('/username/<username>')` and try juust with `add_url_rule`, it is not working.

Comment: You can't remove the `@app.route...`, period. It has to be there.

Comment: so is there any way to use existing python files and its function and generate all the endpoints dynamically?

Comment: uhh... that's what you're doing...

Comment: So i have a python class Users. I want to change all its methods to endpoints without changing anything in this Users class.
So i want to access all the methods of Users class in another python class and use app.add_url_rule('/username/', 'userstatus', defaults={"username":None}, 
there are other classes with many methods, and endpoint generation should be common for all. so i dont want to add "@app.route" in every class on every method. Is there a way to do that?? I am able to pull the classes and its methods + arguments already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide the rule, the end point and the view function to `add_url_rule` ([see API doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule)):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


def userstatus(username):
    return f'Hello {username}!'


app.add_url_rule('/username/<username>', '/username/<username>', userstatus)
```

Then you can start your flask app:

```
(venv) $ FLASK_APP=url_rule.py flask run
 * Serving Flask app "url_rule.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

And send queries in a different shell (or your browser):

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/username/alice && echo
Hello alice!
$ curl http://localhost:5000/username/bob && echo
Hello bob!
```

You could then use your existing python files and call `add_url_rule` for the endpoints you want to create dynamically.